# Is it possible for one process to change the value of a variable in another process at runtime?

Tags: c, memory, stack

Is it possible for one executable (process) to modify the value of a variable of another executable (process) during runtime?

Comment: Of course, debuggers do it all the time.

Comment: In the ordinary course of events, no.  If the processes share some shared memory, then yes.  If one of the processes is a debugger, then yes.  But your average process cannot change a variable in another process.  (Oh, there's also a window of vulnerability in the parent process after creating a child with `vfork()` — the child might modify the parent's variables, but to do so invokes undefined behaviour.  The POSIX rules on the use of `vfork()` are very stringent.)

Comment: I think a process might be able to launch the debugger against another process.

Comment: https://www.cheatengine.org/ or any other game cheat/trainer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. For e.g. The Linux operating system provides `ptrace` system call's by which you can not only examine but change the tracee's memory. From **[`ptrace`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html)** [emphasis added]:

> The ptrace() system call provides a means by which one process (the "tracer") may **observe and control the execution of another process** (the "tracee"), and **examine and change the tracee's memory and registers**. It is primarily used to implement breakpoint debugging and system call tracing.

Answer (score 0):

Possible, yes, but not guaranteed.

In normal operation, the address space of each process is completely separate.

Processes can use shared memory to allow access to the same memory region in different processes (noting that the address at which the region is visible in each process is not necessarily the same).  In most operating systems, you can even map files that way.

Operating systems provide various facilities to help with development and debugging.  In Linux and BSDs (originally from Unix System V), the [ptrace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) interface is probably the most powerful.  In general, the interface works between processes running under the same user ID, and requires superuser privileges to use otherwise.  (In Linux, depending on the kernel configuration, it may also be possible to manipulate the memory contents each process sees directly, via `/proc/PID/mem`. This too has similar security considerations.)

In Linux, a process can call [`prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE, 0uL)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html) to make itself and its children not ptraceable.  This is common for example when a privileged service starts a helper process that does something on behalf of an unprivileged user, but that helper process needs to be secure against manipulation by that user (for example, the helper process returns some privileged data the user should not be able to spoof or fake).

(In fact, if a process changes its identity via the `seteuid()`, `setegid()`, `setfsuid()`, `setfsgid()`, or related calls, or the process was executed as a setuid/setgid binary, or gained extra capabilities based on filesystem capabilities for its binary, the kernel automatically does an equivalent of the above prctl() call, disallowing ptracing such processes.)

The dynamic linker in Linux can also be used to interpose or inject code to any (non-setuid/setgid/gaining-capabilities) process the user starts, by specifying the paths to those extra dynamic libraries in the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable. This allows things like replacing standard C library functions with your own wrappers.  The ELF executable file format also supports "constructors" and "destructors"; functions that get automatically called when the binary is executed and exits (before and after `main()`, that is). These allow you to essentially inject a small service to any processes you start (that run with your own user account and your user privileges), that you can remotely connect to, and do mischief to the process, like redirecting files, or changing data stored at some memory addresses.

As you can see, the better question is *how* and *when* one process can change the value of a variable in another process at runtime.  And the answer to that depends on the situation.  The most common case is to have the two processes talk to each other -- interprocess communication --, so that the target process actually does the modification when asked to do so by the other process.  The solutions vary depending on the exact situation -- and the OS used, of course; my answer here is specific to Linux, but similar or related features are available in all operating systems, they just vary a bit.

Comment: @Ry-: It is, indeed. Now fixed. Thank you for noticing this!